# I was meeting vs. I met

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I **was** **meeting** some friends at a bar.

I **met** some friends at a bar.

**was** **meeting** - past continuous

**met** - simple past

In my opinion, I prefer to use the latter sentence because I don't normally hear people say **was** **meeting**.

In the sentence: "He **met** a lot of friendly people while he **was** **working** in Chicago."

I can't use the words "**was** **meeting**" because he couldn't do both actions at the same time (simultaneously).

However, I am still confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As is very often the case with tenses in English, both are possible, depending on how you are choosing to view the temporal structure of the events, rather than on an objective difference in the events.

If you use *I was meeting*, it suggests that you are choosing to view the meeting as a continuing process, probably because you are then going to relate something that happened during the process, eg *I was meeting some friends at a bar, when I remembered something.*

Another possible meaning for this is something like "I was intending to, or had arranged to, meet some friends at a bar"